# Can't display data after triggering asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, async-await

After I triggered an asychronous function in each traversal, I encountered 403 request errors and couldn't display the array.

I'm trying to display an array of GitHub profiles in the following sandbox. However, some 403 request errors pop up in the console panel demonstrated in the attached screenshot, and there are no profiles in the array when I console log it. How can I fix those problems?

Here is the sandbox: https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/Pq1HA68eeHsnXqEE

Here is the code:

```
const givenUsernames = ["blablabla", "PhucDong"];

  async function getUsers(username) {

    const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`);
    
    if (response.status === 200) {
      const result = await response.json();
      return result;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
 
  let validUsernames = givenUsernames.map(givenUsername => getUsers(givenUsername)
      .then(successResponse => successResponse),
      failResponse => failResponse);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(validUsernames));
```

Comment: You want to try `console.log(JSON.parse(successResponse));` 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap your result in an object that represents whether the API call was successful or not.

If you use this code:

```js
const givenUsernames = ["blablabla", "PhucDong"];

async function getUsers(username) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`);
    return {
      success: true,
      user: await response.json()
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      success: false,
      error
    }
  }    
}

let users = Promise.all(givenUsernames.map(getUsers)).then(users => {
  console.log(22, JSON.stringify(users));
})
```

You can execute all API calls and store them in the `users` array. Inside that array will be objects that either have `success` set to `true` and have a user inside the `user` field, or the `success` property will be `false` and the `error` property will contain the error that was thrown during the API call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to add that you don't have to specify an object for the return value since the **result** variable is already an object. Also, I have 2 questions:
1.  In the **map** method you only use **getUsers**. Is this similar to **username => getUsers(username)** as well?
2.  What does **Promise.all** do?

Comment: Yes, `usernames.map(getUser)` is shorthand for `usernames.map(username => getUser(username))`, where we pass the reference of the function directly. [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) allows you to await all the promises. So, it will return a list of the API request results.